# Hiding or removing a path during export but not the text in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, path, export, background-removal

I've made a circular logo design in illustrator using the 'type on a path' feature.  To type in the bottom of the circle I used a oval path.  Now, when I go to export it as an .eps or .jpeg it includes the space for the transparent path even though it is outside of the artboard.  Is there a way to no include this path in an export/saved file?
[image: Here'a picture of what it looks like in illustrator]

[image: The second picture is what it looks like when I export it with the extra space on top]

Comment: When you export as jpeg or png, choose the option to "use artboards".

Comment: Unfortunately, clip to artboard will add transparent pixels in areas where art may not be exactly at artboard edges.

Answer (score 1):

- `Select > Select All`
- `Type >  Create Outlines`
- `File > Export`
- `Edit > Undo Create Outlines`

By creating outlines you eliminate the path the type is sitting on and the export won't have any problems.

Be certain to **Undo** after the export... or copy/paste to a new file then create outlines and export and then merely don't save the new file.